# Matplotlib: coloring violinplots with multiple colors depending on modalities

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm searching how to achieve a plot with multiple violinplot of the measures of an response from a dataset with two modalities (time and treatment). 
I succeeded to plot this violinplot but cannot succeed to color each treatment responses with a specific color. I search for a simple stuff: I d'ont want to color edges, etc.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy

Lcolor = ['red','green','blue'] # targeted colors per treatment

## create a dataset with 2 columns of two modalities (remark: not the purpose of the question)
a = numpy.random.randn(60,1) # create the random variable "measure"
# create the modalities
Ltime = [1,3]
Ltreatment = [0.2,0.6,0.8]
modalities = [[0.2,1], [0.2,3], [0.6, 1], [0.6, 3], [0.8, 1], [0.8,3]]
tempList = []
for i in modalities:
    tempList.extend([i]*10)
NpModLis = numpy.array(tempList)
# create a list of violinplot positions
position = [1.2,1.6, 1.8, 3.2, 3.6, 3.8]

# merging into a 2d-array of modalities and the random variable
DATA = numpy.c_[NpModLis,a]

## Dataset is made of first column: treatment, second column: time of mesure, third column: response measure

# Now I want to plot with violin plot for each time, the three violinplots due to treatment, each violinplot with a color specific to treatment

Lcolors = ['red','green','blue'] # respectively fro treatment 0.2, 0.6, 0.8

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9, 4))

data=[]
for i in range(len(Ltime)):
    j=Ltime[i]
    for k in Ltreatment:
        data.append(DATA[numpy.logical_and(DATA[:,0]==k,DATA[:,1]==j)][:,2])

ax.violinplot(data, position)  # which isd violinplot(measure of one treatment at one time, position)
plt.show()
```

thanks for helping and commented answers to understand ^^

Answer (score 1):

`violinplot()` returns a dictionary with the artists that were created, so you can modify their properties. Here is something that seems to get you the desired ouput

```
out = ax.violinplot(data, position)  # which isd violinplot(measure of one treatment at one time, position)
for b,c in zip(out['bodies'],itertools.islice(itertools.cycle(Lcolors), 0, len(out['bodies']))):
    b.set_facecolor(c)
```

However, I would suggest that you use [seaborn's violingplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.violinplot.html?highlight=violinplot#seaborn.violinplot) instead. You would have to refactor the format of your data, but it would simplify the plotting part.